# need to set video file name using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Below is the code to play media player on the page. Now i want to set the value of filename and src in embed using javascript. I mean i want to put the video file name using javascript so every time it will be set on button click

```
<div id="MideaPlayer" style="display: none">
<object classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" height="270" width="300" codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" style="height: 236px">
<param name="Filename" value="http://localhost:4047/Videos/1/New1/m2.mp4">
<param name="AutoStart" value="false">
<param name="ShowControls" value="true">
<param name="BufferingTime" value="2">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
<param name="AutoSize" value="true">
<param name="InvokeURLs" value="false">
<embed src="http://localhost:4047/Videos/1/New1/m2.mp4" type="application/x-mplayer2" autostart="0" enabled="1" showstatusbar="1" showdisplay="1" showcontrols="1" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,0,0,0" width="480" height="360"></embed>
</object>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to set the path to your video dynamically through JavaScript using jQuery.

```
$('#MideaPlayer object param[name="Filename"]').attr('value', '/Videos/1/New1/m2.mp4');
$('#MideaPlayer object embed').attr('src', '/Videos/1/New1/m2.mp4');
```

Just put that in your button click handler.

Comment: BTW not to be a smart a$$, but "MediaPlayer" ***

Comment: Sorry, I edited that without realising the error was in the question because of the comment above.