# Dynamically set source for embed tag

Tags: java, html, streaming, zk, ip-camera

I was able to embed a media player plugin in zul page and play a video(which comes from an ip camera) by specifying the src,now I was trying do give the source file dynamically but I was not able to get it work.can anyone help me with this.
Thanks in advance

videoPage.zul goes like this

```
<zscript>
String filePath = (String) Executions.getCurrent().getSession()
.getAttribute("urlReturned");
</zscript>
<p:window xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="192" HEIGHT="190"
CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..."
TYPE="application/x-oleobject">
<param name="FileName" value='${filePath}' />
<PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="false" />
<EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" 
SRC=""
NAME="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="300" ShowControls="0"
ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="1">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
</p:window>
</p:zk>
```

i would like the path(in my case from a url from an ip camera) at runtime based camera selected by user and display it in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

you can set `src` of `embed` tag in javascript, for that you **must** have to write your embed tag in javascript like below example :

```
    function onclickofSomething()
{
    $('#IDOfParentElement').html("<embed type='application/x-mplayer2' pluginspage='http:///www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/' src='" + "<%=YourVideoPath%>" + "YourVideoName" + ID + ".mp4/wmv" + "' autostart='1' showstatusbar='1' enabled='1' showdisplay='1' showcontrols='1' width='630' height='380'></embed>");
};
```

you can also see below url :
[need to set video file name using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961825/need-to-set-video-file-name-using-javascript)
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?53086-how-to-change-the-src-in-lt-embed-gt-using-javascript
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/16626/how-to-change-the-the-value-of-src-in-embed-using-javascript